# Invalid command: KillProcDLL::KillProc NSIS

Tags: plugins, installation, nsis

I install the latest version of the NSIS 3.0b0 version (latest one up today)
I copy the KillProcDLL plug-in to plug-in folder.
Try to compile a working script (didn't touch it - was working), but keep getting the Invalid command: KillProcDLL::KillProc.

Comment: The plugin folder structure changed in 3.0 because of Unicode and 64 bit support...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the issue is the current version (3.0b0)

Solution:

1. Uninstall NSIS 3.0b0 version
2. Install prev. version NSIS 2.46
3. Copy the illProcDLL plug-in to plug-in folder

Answer (score 2):

NSIS 3.0 uses a different folder structure. You have to copy the KillProc plugin into the right subfolder of NSIS\Plugins!